# Can't add items from database to list

Tags: java, android

i am trying to add some items from database to my list but when i run the application i see that the list is empty.

this is what i did to add items to a list

```
car_size = dbHelper.getSize("cars"); // getSize is a method that count items in database

Random random = new Random();
int cars_random = random.nextInt(car_size);

List<String> myList = dbHelper.read_added_names("cars"); // and this line should add items from database to the list

if(myList!= null && myList.size() > 0) {
        textView.setText(myList.get(truth_random));

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(activity.this, "" + myList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }  // here i can see that the size of my list is 0 and it's empty
```

I'm sure the methode that should read database (here i named it read_aded_names) works fine

```
public List<String> read_added_names (String subject){
    String selectQuery;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (subject.equals("*")) {
        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1;
    }else {
        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1 + " WHERE " + COLUMN_SUBJECT  + " = '" + subject+" '";
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: are there any entries with subject named as "cars" in the database ?

Comment: yes i'm sure there is some items with cars subject

Answer (score 0):

Query contains space after subject variable making it "cars " instead of "cars". This can be the issue.

Comment: R you getting non zero value of car_size?